# Null safety error showing after checking for null

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I perform a function (`listOf(matchUid, first_name, gender, matchBio, age).any { it == null }`) that checks if any of the variables passed in are `null`:

```
private fun getMatchData(doc: DocumentSnapshot){
    val matchUid = if (isUser1) doc.getString("user2") else doc.getString("user1")
    val first_name = if (isUser1) doc.getString("user2name") else doc.getString("user1name")
    val gender = if (isUser1) doc.getString("user2gender") else doc.getString("gender")
    val matchBio = if (isUser1) doc.getString("user2bio") else doc.getString("user1bio")
    if ( listOf(matchUid, first_name, gender, matchBio, age).any { it == null } ) return goOffline()
    if (matchUid == null) return goOffline()
    if (!isUser1) Group = Group().apply {
        id = doc.id
        user1 = matchUid
        user2 = user.uid
        match = User(matchUid, first_name, gender, null, true)
    }
```

Even though it checks this, `first_name` and `gender` have red underlines from the compiler due to null safety. `matchUid` doesn't have a red line because I explicitly check for null on it the line below.

Why is the compiler still giving a null warning after I already check it?

Comment: I presume because the compiler is not smart enough.

Comment: I'd say that the compiler can't know what you're doing with the list or whether you might map elements to something else. Being able to do so would require a measure of code analysis that's probably way out of scope for most compilers. Even you as a human might not be able to tell what's actually going on if you don't know what exactly `listOf(...)` is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem is that compiler is not smart enough, or... we do not provide enough information.

In your case the problematic call where you ensure that `firstName` and `gender` is not null is:

```
if (listOf(matchUid, firstName, gender, matchBio, age).any { it == null }) return goOffline()
```

If you change it to simple chain of nulls it would working properly:

```
if (matchUid == null || firstName == null || gender == null || matchBio == null || age == null) return goOffline()
```

So, why is that? Compiler just don't know that `listOf(vararg objects: Any?).any { it == null }` means, that none of that objects are not null.
So, what we can do?

Kotlin 1.3 gave us a great possibility to write `contracts`, which are a tip for compilator that, for example, if `f(x)` returns `true` means `x` is not null. But, unfortunately, contracts doesn't support varargs argument (or I haven't found a way to do that).

So, in your case you can replace your call with chain of single null checking.